# Changing div left property set in % using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hope you can help me!! So I have a div inside another div and I'd like to move the second one back and forth with a step of 14.5% left and right stopping it before the black edges. I've managed to do it setting the left property in px but I'd like to to that with percentages..how can I do that? Thanks in advance!
PS. of course now the code doesn't work well because of the px changing..for this reason I'd like to work with %s...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#min_oct').click(function() {
      var left = parseFloat($('.highlighted').css('left'));
      console.log(left);
      if(left<99.495){
        $('.highlighted').css('left',left);
      }
      else{
        left= left - 103.108;
        $('.highlighted').css('left',left);
      }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#plus_oct').click(function() {
      var left = parseFloat($('.highlighted').css('left'));
      console.log(left);
      if(left>411.111){
        $('#highlighted').css('left',left);
      }
      else{
        left= left +  103.108;
        $('#highlighted').css('left',left);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.mini_keyboard{
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;;
  height: 90px;
  top: 22.5%;
  transform: translate(35%);
  border: 0.5rem solid;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 0 18rem black,
    inset 0 0 4rem black,
    0 0 10rem black;
  padding: 0.5%;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.highlighted{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 198px;;
  height: 93px;
  left: 57.5%;
  top: 0.5%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  padding: 0.5%;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mini_keyboard">

  <div id=highlight class="highlighted"></div>
</div>

<button id="min_oct">-1 octave</button>
<button id="plus_oct">+1 octave</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your highlighted id is missing `"` and you're are trying to get your element by calling the id attribute with the class value.

You can get the container width with `.width()` function, and then calculate the percentage by multiplying it by 0.145.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#min_oct').click(function() {
      var containerWidth = $(".mini_keyboard").width();
      var left = parseFloat($('.highlighted').css('left'));
      console.log(left);
      var step = (containerWidth * 0.145);
      if(left < step){
        $('#highlight').css('left',left);
      }
      else{
        left= left - step;
        $('#highlight').css('left',left);
      }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#plus_oct').click(function() {
      var containerWidth = $(".mini_keyboard").width();
      var left = parseFloat($('.highlighted').css('left'));
      console.log(left);
      var step = (containerWidth * 0.145);
      if(left > (containerWidth - (2*step))){
        $('#highlight').css('left',left);
      }
      else{
        left = left + step;
        $('#highlight').css('left',left);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.mini_keyboard{
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;;
  height: 90px;
  top: 22.5%;
  transform: translate(35%);
  border: 0.5rem solid;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 0 18rem black,
    inset 0 0 4rem black,
    0 0 10rem black;
  padding: 0.5%;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.highlighted{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 198px;;
  height: 93px;
  left: 57.5%;
  top: 0.5%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  padding: 0.5%;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mini_keyboard">

  <div id="highlight" class="highlighted"></div>
</div>

<button id="min_oct">-1 octave</button>
<button id="plus_oct">+1 octave</button>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! Anyway everything is fine until I move the div back and forth twice..if I move it back and forth further it stops moving before the end of the image..

Comment: In my example it seems to work fine. Can you provide an example with your problem?